# POI in OpenLayer 3

Tags: openlayers-3

If load points from KML file to vetor layer

```
var layerPOI = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.KML({
    projection: projection,
    url: 'data/KML/mydata.kml'
  })
})
```

How can I do a complete listing of all loaded points (POIs) and loaded properties (from data/KML/mydata.kml)? I think, for example, into the table - in map view (display layer) I can is already

Thank you very much for answer

Answer (score 0):

`ol.source.KML` has a method [getFeatures()](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.source.KML.html?unstable=true#getFeatures) which gives you all features in your KML. Then you can use [getProperties()](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Feature.html?unstable=true#getProperties) or [get()](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Feature.html?unstable=true#get) on the feature to read the properties.

Comment: Thanks so much. But the element `GEOMTERY` returns Object. I try to getting additional information about point yet but I can not - please still help. Also more tags from KML file - For example, point style - how to determine the displayed icon. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

**(Partial) solution:**

```
allPOIs = layerPOI.getSource().getFeatures();
// or if define a source separatly
// allPOIs = sourcePOI.getFeatures(); 
onePOI = allPOIs[0]; // first element in Array
propertiesOfOnePOI = onePOI.getKeys();

propertiesOfOnePOI.forEach(function (elementName, elementIndex){
    console.log( "element index: " + elementIndex + " | element name: " + elementName + " | element value: " + onePOI.get(elementName) );
});
```

But the element `GEOMTERY` returns Object.
I try to getting additional information about point yet but I can not - 
Also more tags from KML file - For example, point style - how to determine the displayed icon?

Please still help ;)