# openlayers 4 get features from ol.layer.Vector

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm new to OpenLayers, so I'm kind of lost here.
I'm trying to get all features from a kml vector layer, but I haven't been able to do it. I just don't understand what am I doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
var vector2 = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: './energeticos.kml',
        format: new ol.format.KML()
    })
});

var features = vector2.getSource().getFeatures();
alert(features.length); //this alerts '0', but there's more than 50 features!!

for (var i in features) {
    var feature = features[i];
    var featureName = feature.get('name');
    $("#containerLeft").append('<li>' + featureName + '</li>');
}
```

the kml layer is properly displayed on the map, and as it's mentioned in the code, when I use the getFeatures function, it doesn't get anything.

any help will be really appreciated.

P.S. I'll try to get some sleep, so I'll be back in a few hours.

Comment: Needless to say, the for loop doesn't do anything, since "features" array is apparently empty. What I'm trying to do is to create hyperlinks outside of the map, that will center the map on a particular polygon and show it's respective popup. Right now, you can see the popup when some area/polygon is clicked. Anyone? any clue??

Comment: Are you able to see the features on the map?

Comment: yes, I can see all features in the map, I've can display a popup with each feature info when it's clicked as well

Answer (score 1):

I've just found a solution here:

[getFeatures() is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432645/getfeatures-is-empty)

I had to add an event listener since the loading of the KML-file will happen in an asynchronous manner, as it's explained in that answer.

Comment: right, if you call the function when it's visible on the map, it returns features.

Answer (score 0):

You can type `vector2.getSource().getFeatures()` individually on Console. Seems like rendering KML is asynchronous.